# SQL- Why do I need to use joins?

Tags: sql, join

Please give me an example situation of why someone would need to join two (or more) tables? It seems to me that you are not gaining any information by joining two tables that you couldn't do another way, so why not just query the tables individually then to find the values you need?

I understand what joins do and how to do them. My trouble is understanding the why and when to use them.

Comment: I dont understand the negative votes, please explain. I have researched this a lot and most sources just show how to join tables and not why to. Please help me, I'm just trying to learn!

Comment: You know what joins do and how to do them but don't understand why they are useful. that's real strange!

Comment: "why not **just** query the tables individually" -> What makes you think that's simpler? You "just" join them and let your SQL server do the work.

Comment: Again i don't understand the negative votes? Again I researched this and cannot find an explanation that satisfies me, I believe my question is clear, and i was always told theres no such thing as a dump question.... So what am I missing here?

Comment: When you want data from more then one table you have to use a join. What is hard to understand about that?

Comment: You have a table `Post (PostId, PostTitle, AuthorId)` and a table `Author (AuthorID, AuthorName)`. How would you go about getting a list of the format `Post Title | Author Name` ? Would you `select * from Posts` and `select * from Authors` and then write some code to match them up yourself? Or would you write one simple SQL `join` and get the data in the correct format straight from the DB?

Comment: You are talking about doing 2 queries instead of doing 1?  Or are you just talking about a query that uses the word `join` vs one that just lists the tables?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I think i'm good now, your situation was helpful, thanks.

Comment: @paqogomez I am talking about using two queries. Select PostTile where AuthorID = '123', select AuthorName where AuthorID = '123'

Comment: A big part of the time for a web page or app to load is waiting on information from the database to load.  1 query vs 2 is twice as fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins are used when parsing data from two or more tables so that you can attain refined search-results. For example, if I own a shop, and I have three tables of data:'Products', 'Invoices','Customers', where each invoice features a Customer's ID and the ID of each of the products purchased during that transaction, I can attain what product-type that customer typically buys, so that I may send them information on future products which are of a similar nature. This query would be done using a join.

Comment: I have a much better understanding now, and i think thinking about it in terms of refining search results is easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By making multiple queries and joining the data in code will make multiple requests to your database, one for each table you need data from.  The advantage of using a `join` in the `SQL` query will reduce the number of connection made to just one.  This is especially advantageous if your database server is on a separate machine.  By using the a `join` in the `SQL` query you are reducing I/O.